# can we assign value to the request variable of srv file other then run time?

Tags: ros, linux, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

with an example,

AddTwoInts.srv

int64 a

int64 b

---

int64 sum

**client.cpp**

srv.request.a =atoll(argv[1]);

srv. request.b =atoll(argv[2]);

/* which takes the value during run time */

can I assign the value of a and b during writing of the code? pre assign of the value to the variable ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301177/can-we-assign-value-to-the-request-variable-of-srv-file-other-then-run-time-?/) by [rama_bhuyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35033/rama_bhuyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. Like any other variable, you can assign any value to the service request parameters. (could come from user input, a file, or just a pre-assigned value).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0